# Freely available example datasets of hierarchical information, and realistic names

Tags: sql, mysql, database, postgresql

I'm about to write some example applications and accompanying documents comparing ways of accessing information stored in relational databases. To demonstrate real-life requirements, I need to include a realistic dataset of hundreds of thousands of facts.

Is anyone aware of publicly available, free datasets of that magnitude, of datasets of **human names** with human-level variance, or **hierarchical** datasets of either large **organizational hierarchies**, or large hierarchical, categorized, **product catalogues**?

Please point me in the right direction, if you are.

---

Part 1, human names: http://timecenter.cs.aau.dk/software.htm

Part 2, hierarchical data: no answer yet

Comment: What's wrong with generating it randomly? Surely the effort of massaging the data to fit your model would be the same if not more effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila.html

Comment: This led me to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/#sampledb which has several promising leads. 
Thank you.

Comment: Further examination led to http://timecenter.cs.aau.dk/software.htm which has a pretty nice simulated employee database, which MySQL uses in its own sample databases.

Comment: Broken link, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/ seems to work

Answer (score 3):

The wikipedia dump is pretty massive: [obligatory wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database).

Answer (score 3):

Your own PC's directory tree is a large hierarchical structure with lots of facts.  You probably have a few thousand "Facts" which are file names, modification dates, sizes, extra OS info, etc., etc.

If that's not large enough, find a server that you can login to.  That will be larger.

Not large enough?  Get a web crawler and start crawling a big web site.  That can be as large as you have the patience to crawl.

Comment: Merely having a bunch of hierarchical node link data will not serve the purpose of helping the reader understand how a specific demonstrated solution provides the wanted results. For that, the data must provide the reader with understandable hierarchical context, such as an organizational hierarchy, or the categorical hierarchy of a tools catalog.

Comment: A filesystem is a standard, widely understood, almost universal "hierarchical context".  It seems far more universal than organizations or a tools catalog.